# Does running cron by itself have the same behavior as via the init.d script?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, service, ubuntu-18.04, init.d

I'm working with some code that fires up cron on a server (which doesn't have it running at boot time). The script which starts cron sets up some logging stuff and then simply invokes `cron`. It doesn't use `/etc/init.d/cron` or `service cron start`.

After starting cron this way, `service cron status` and `service cron stop` seem to be happily able to work, and the PIDFILE specified in `/etc/init.d/cron` is present.

I put a log line into `/etc/init.d/cron`, and it looks like running `cron` standalone does not invoke the script.

```
# service cron status
script is running
 * cron is running
# service cron stop
script is running
 * Stopping periodic command scheduler cron                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
# cron
#
```

What's going on here? Is this simply because the `cron` binary and the /etc/init.d/cron script use the same convention for the location of the pidfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct: **Vixie Cron** has a fixed pidfile location (`/var/run/crond.pid`), which also prevents running it twice.

The **init.d** script, which is also called by `service` uses the standard `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, which sum up to:

1. The `start` action just calls `/usr/sbin/cron` (through the `/sbin/start-stop-daemon` helper),
2. The `stop` action just sends `SIGTERM` to the PID in the pidfile (through `/sbin/start-stop-daemon`),
3. The `status` action amounts to `kill -0 $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)`.

However, if you have **systemd** installed, the standard init functions are rewritten in `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd` and running **cron** directly is not detected any more:

```
piotr@bialykiel:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/cron 
piotr@bialykiel:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2020-02-02 09:12:43 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
  Process: 734 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 734 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
```

since **systemd** would like to have a `CGroup` per service. What is worse `start` and `restart` won't work, since **cron** will fail on the already existing pidfile and `stop` will not kill the **cron** instance you created.